# How to connect Postgres ReadRepica for Reads without affecting the application source code

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, go, read-replication

I have an application which has read and write inline queries in the code, I am facing a challenge while pointing the read and write queries to respective Databases. Is there any best of doing it for Go application?

My thought is to have two ORMs up with Read and Write databases and select appropriate based on the operation. e.g: ReadDbMap.Select("query"); WriteDbMap.Update("query");

But this change effects entire application, that is the concern I have

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that there is no simpler way.

Streaming replication is not primarily a load balancing feature. For one, you'll have to be aware that a change you made on the primary server is not immediately visible on the standby, so your application will have to deal with these temporary inconsistencies.

Comment: You also can't share a transaction between two connections, which would break any transactional code if the driver tried to split queries automatically between two connections.

Comment: @Adrian Of course, but you would run such a transaction on the primary anyway.